# Framework7 redirect issue

Tags: html-framework-7

This is my js code for registration page in Framework7:

```
myApp.onPageInit('register', function (page) {
// Function to handle Submit button on Register page
$$('#signup').on('click', function () {

 var username = $$('#fullname').val();
 var email = $$('#email').val();
 var password = $$('#password').val();

 if(!username || !password || !email){
  myApp.alert('Please fill in all Registration form fields');
  return;
 }
});
});
```

I get an alert of "Please fill in ..... " however it immediately redirects to the previous page.

Any help in this issue will be highly appreciated.

Thanks,
Utpal

Answer (score 2):

If I understand your issue correctly, the alert closes by itself and you are redirected to the previous page. If you look at Framework7 documentation the "myApp.alert()" function can take up to 3 overloads (alert text, alert title, callback function after you push the OK button).

Suggested solution:

```
if(!username || !password || !email){
myApp.alert('Please fill in all Registration form fields', "", function(){return false;});

 }
```